# loop through sql result with duplicate values and show only line with some string with perl

Tags: perl, hash, unique

I am selecting from sql three values, hostname, place, message, assigning them to hashref and then in loop printing into file. Before I print it I have to clean the message as it contains in DB plenty of mess like html tags etc

```
while (my $result = $sth_get_message->fetchrow_hashref) {
    my $message = $result->{MESSAGE};
    $message =~ s/<[^>]*>//g;
    $message =~ s/\n/ /g;
    $message =~ s/&nbsp;|&quot;/ /g;
    $message =~ s/\r//g;

    my $message_out;
    if (index($message, 'removed') != -1) {$message_out = $message;} else {$message_out= "";}

    my $pc = $result->{PC};
    my $place = $result->{PLACE};
    print OUT "$pc|$message_out|$place\n";
```

}

the result is like this

```
pc1||place
pc2|message with word removed|place
pc3||place
pc3|message with word removed|place
pc4||place
pc4||place
pc4|message with word removed|place
```

some of them have more messages, but only one is relevant, so rest is cleaned but I have duplicates of pc's. What I want to get is to have unique pc list and if it has no message ok, show blank, if it has message with removed, show only this line

```
pc1||place
pc2|message with word removed|place
pc3|message with word removed|place
pc4|message with word removed|place
```

as far as I understood perl hashes this should be possible if I put pc as a key and then work with values but I have no clue how

thanks for help

Comment: Why can you not use your database query to filter this?

Comment: There are time when you have complex queries including subqueries that are not easily represented in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a list of values that you wish to find the unique values for you can populate a hash along these lines:

```
my $hashref = {}; ## initialise an empty hashref .. nb I prefer to work with refs but you could use has hash type variable

foreach my $row ( $rows )
{
  $hashref->{$row} = 1;
}
```

### now you have a hasref that is indexed by unique keys so you can do the following

```
print join(",",  keys %$hashref );
```

or

```
foreach my $unique_key ( sort keys %$hashref )
{
  print "$unique key in sorted order\n";
}
```

In your case you could use the string with the fields concatenated or you could just use the values that you wish to make unique and then assign something containing the entire row detail you are interested in place of the 1 value used above as a placeholder. You are then able to retrieve the full row detail with something like  `$hashref->{$unique_key}`